# Which permission system should I use in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, relational-database, user-permissions

im working in a Django project that aims to manage warehouses, items and presonell.
I have the following models: WarehouseMode, ItemModel and PersonellModel.

The admin must be able to create users and assign to them one of the followin roles:

1. Admin - full access.
2. Warehouse admin - limited access (add, delete, modify items and presonell)
3. Individual warehouse user - limited access (modify personal profile)
4. Other database subscribers - (read-only)

The "warehouse admin" should be the "owner" of just one warehouse.

Which permission system should I use? Per row permission system?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Row-level permissions will definitely make your life easier in the end for this implementation, but speaking from experience it is definitely something you should write out the flow for separate from anything else and do a lot of testing. A structure I used recently with row-level permissions is below.

After trying out a few my preference is django-guardian, and I found it worked much better (from an ease of implementing the structure I devised) to use class-based views and mixins.

https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian.git

```
class Meta:
    permissions = (
    ('can_view', 'View project'),
    ('manage_view', 'Can assign View project'),
    ('can_edit', 'Edit project'),
    ('manage_edit', 'Can assign Edit project'),
    ('can_delete', 'Delete project'),
    ('manage_delete', 'Can assign Delete project'),
    ('creator', 'Full access to model features.'),
    )
```